# RecyclerView not showing under TextView for ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have this layout and I used ConstraintLayout. The code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVwCount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="the count is: 5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

    <view
    android:id="@+id/rclrVw"
    class="androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtVwCount"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       />



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/rclrVw"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="addNewTodo"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Isnt it supposed to show the textview at the top and underneath the textView it will show recyclerView? Why are they overlapping?

Comment: paste screenshot from layout editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `android:layout_height` of the `RecyclerView` to `0dp` (also known as [ConstraintLayout.MATCH_CONSTRAINT](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints)).  It's currently `match_parent`, so it's filling the entire parent size.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `match_parent` that's why it was filling the entire layout height as parent height. all you need to do is set height to `0dp` it will automatically manage its height.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVwCount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="the count is: 5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/rclrVw"
        class="androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtVwCount"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/rclrVw"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="addNewTodo"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: you can use these two options as well while using match parent app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"  or  app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

Answer (score 0):

**Just add following two lines:**

android:layout_height="0dp"

app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtVwCount"

Comment: This is incorrect.  Assuming you meant to add these into the RecyclerView tag, it already has both of those defined, but the `layout_height` needs to be changed.  If you simply add those, you'll get an error.  Additionally, there's no need to change the start constraint, as it's already correct.

Comment: After setting android:layout_height of the RecyclerView to 0dp problem remains same because of that i suggest to add this more line app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtVwCount"

Answer (score 0):

**Change width and height of view as 0dp instead of match_parent**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVwCount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="the count is: 5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<view
    android:id="@+id/rclrVw"
    class="androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtVwCount"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/rclrVw"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="addNewTodo"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```